# Gradle: Set context root of web application

Tags: gradle, jakarta-ee, ear

I have 2 Gradle projects, A is the root, and B is a subproject of A.

Project B generates a `.war` file, which is included in the `.ear` file, that project A generates.

I'd like to implement a general solution, where I can change the context root of project B.

Based on my research, I should call the `ear.deploymentDescriptors.webModule(path, contextRoot)` method, where `path` is the path of the artifact B in the ear.

How can I get the name of the artifact of B from project A, so that I have something to call the above mentioned method?

Is there a better way to set the context root?

Answer (score 0):

Assume project A has a build.gradle and within ear, the below code can be solve this -

```
plugins {
  id 'ear'
}

dependencies {
   deploy project(path:':b', configuration: 'archives')
}

ear{
     /* some basis configuration */
    libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'
    deploymentDescriptor {
      /* Some basic attributes */
      fileName = "application.xml"
      version = "8"
      def Set<Project> subProj = project.getSubprojects();
      subProj.each{proj -> 
        if(proj.name.contains("B")){
          webModule(proj.name + "-" + proj.version + ".war", "/"+ proj.name)
        } //if close
      }//each close
    }//deploymentDescriptor close

}//ear close
```